# how to get value from Marquee to show in lable using JS/JQ/

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

```
    <marquee id="marquee_element" class="marquee_element">
        <span class="notification_marquee first ">{{$announcement->announcement1}}</span>
        <span class="notification_marquee second not_sec">{{$announcement->announcement2}}</span>
        <span class="notification_marquee third not_3rd">{{$announcement->announcement3}}</span>
        <span class="notification_marquee fourth not_4th">{{$announcement->announcement4}}</span>
        <span class="notification_marquee fifth not_5th">{{$announcement->announcement5}}</span>
     </marquee>
```

i want to print marquee value which in on sceen i have to also print on lable

```
  <span id="an_label_1" class="an_label not_fst"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

HI you can use this code , let me know if any issue you face

```js
var label = $('#marquee1');

console.log(label.text());

$('#an_label_1').text(label.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<marquee id="marquee_element" class="marquee_element">
        <span class="notification_marquee first " id="marquee1">{{$announcement->announcement1}}</span>
        <span class="notification_marquee second not_sec">{{$announcement->announcement2}}</span>
        <span class="notification_marquee third not_3rd">{{$announcement->announcement3}}</span>
        <span class="notification_marquee fourth not_4th">{{$announcement->announcement4}}</span>
        <span class="notification_marquee fifth not_5th">{{$announcement->announcement5}}</span>
     </marquee>
     
      <span id="an_label_1" class="an_label not_fst"></span>
```

Comment: Actually i have to every  marquee value  that is slide on sceen .... if 1st one is sliding then 1st one is displaying on lable.. and then after 2nd one is coming label change with 2nd value

Comment: You can set dynamically , Get value from marquee and add in span